# Invest in Motley Fool 100 through UK ISA?

Tags: united-kingdom, shares, isa

Is it possible to invest on a Motley Fool 100 based index through a UK ISA?

Comment: I’m not sure who made the close vote but this is perfectly on topic.

Comment: There is is a difference between "Questions seeking product or service recommendations are off-topic" and the question as asked. I agree with Vicky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not directly.

You need to find a financial institution (i.e. a broker or a fund supermarket) that sells products derived from that index - ETFs, most likely - **and** that allows you to hold and stocks and shares ISA with them.

So if I were to continue from here, I guess that the next step would be to go back to the place where you found the index and ask there about which UK brokers have expressed interest on the index.